# $f$ entire with $f$ bounded in right half plane and $f'$ bounded on the left half plane. Show $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

> Suppose that $f$ is entire, $f$ is bounded when the real part of $z$ is $\geq 0$ and $f'$ is bounded when the real part of $z$ is $\leq 0$. Show that $f$ is constant.

I am not really sure what I should do. I want to bound $f$ on the left half plane by possibly using the cauchy integral formula, but this has not worked because I don't have a bound for $f$ is this region. I am not sure where I am suppose to use $f'$ being bounded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $|f'(z)| \le M, \Re z \le 0$; then $f(z)-f(0)=\int_{[0,z]}f'(z)dz$ and $[0,z]$ is included in the left half-plane if $z$ is, so $|f(z)-f(0)| \le M|z|,\Re z \le 0$

Since $|f| \le M_1$ in the right half-plane, it follows that $|f(z)| \le M|z|+M_1+|f(0)|$ in the plane, so $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1$ and then it is constant because of the right half plane boundness; done!

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: Happy to be of help